# Finding Unique variables from CSV formatted text in a column

Tags: excel, vba, hashmap, keyvaluepair

[image]
Column A contains the list of all counters and column D (onward) contains some related information which I'm extracting from form XML. Now I want to return those variables in column B for which there are multiple values in column D and beyond

For example:

- for counter1, nothing should be returned
- for counter2, "D" should be
  returned as there are 2 unique values(4 and 5) for it
- for counter3, "B,C,D" should be returned as there are multiple values for those 3 variables.

Format is standard, variable-value pairs are separated by comma and there is equal sign between variable and value, but there can be as many number of pairs and as many number of key pair instances(one counter can have up to 100+ such cells in front of them)

Comment: Please see image

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code that you can show us? At what point are you stuck? Have you [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+unique) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+unique)?

Comment: If you have had a look at those similar questions and decided they don't help you - please explain why they aren't helping you.

Comment: Thanks @Inarion, this is part of very long process and currently I'm stuck at what I vaguely explained. My plan is to split the var-value pair in another sheet, find unique among them and return.

Comment: Please check your example for counter 3. What is the expected return? D doesn't seem right. Judging from the 2nd example, it should only return B and C.

Comment: Also, to clear that up, your ruleset seems to be: Search for **multiple assignments** to a variable and return all variable names that get assigned **at least 2 different values**. Is that correct? And again: Please show your coding efforts so far.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the assumption that you want to

> Search for multiple assignments to a variable of the form `X=n` and return all variable names that get assigned at least 2 different values. Multiple assignments within one cell are separated by a defined delimiter. A range of multiple cells that do or do not contain one or more assignments may serve as input.

The below function `FindDuplicateAssignmentsInCSVRange(inputRange, listDelimiter, assignmentOperator` accepts a range of cells and optionally allows to define an alternate list separator (default: comma) and an alternate assignment operator (default: equality symbol).
It outputs as a comma-separated list (or whatever alternate separator has been passed in) the names of all variables that get assigned at least 2 different values. If no variable name fulfills that requirement, an empty string is returned instead.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TKeyValuePair
    key As String
    val As String
End Type

Private Function FindDuplicateAssignmentsInCSVRange(inpRange As Range, _
                                                    Optional ByVal listDelimiter As String = ",", _
                                                    Optional ByVal assingmentOperator As String = "=") As String
    ' this function needs a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to work

    Const ReturnIndicator As String = "Return this value's key when done"
    Dim dic As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dic = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' Go into each cell in the given range
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In inpRange.Cells

        ' split cell contents and iterate over each particle
        Dim particle As Variant
        For Each particle In Split(c.Value, listDelimiter)

            ' split each fragment "A=1" into variable and value; kvp = key-value pair
            Dim kvp As TKeyValuePair
            kvp.key = Split(particle, assingmentOperator)(0)
            kvp.val = Split(particle, assingmentOperator)(1)

            If Not dic.Exists(kvp.key) Then
                ' add new keys/variables to dictionary to keep track
                dic.Add kvp.key, kvp.val
            Else
                ' check values of existing keys and mark key if values differ ( = there are 2 or more different values)
                Dim AlreadyMarkedForReturn As Boolean
                AlreadyMarkedForReturn = (dic(kvp.key) = ReturnIndicator)
                If dic(kvp.key) <> kvp.val And Not AlreadyMarkedForReturn Then
                    dic(kvp.key) = ReturnIndicator
                End If
            End If

        Next particle

    Next c

    ' clean up dictionary to only contain the return entries
    Dim k As Variant
    For Each k In dic.Keys
        If dic(k) <> ReturnIndicator Then dic.Remove k
    Next k

    ' return remaining keys as comma(or whatever)-separated list
    FindDuplicateAssignmentsInCSVRange = Join(dic.Keys, listDelimiter)

End Function
```

---

Example usage:

```
Public Sub SO_51607467()
    Debug.Print "D2:D2 Variables: '" & FindDuplicateAssignmentsInCSVRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D2")) & "'"
    Debug.Print "D3:E3 Variables: '" & FindDuplicateAssignmentsInCSVRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D3:E3")) & "'"
    Debug.Print "D4:F4 Variables: '" & FindDuplicateAssignmentsInCSVRange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D4:F4")) & "'"
End Sub
```

Output of running `SO_51607467` from within an approximate (due to copy-typing) copy of the workbook you showed:

```
D2:D2 Variables: ''
D3:E3 Variables: 'D'
D4:F4 Variables: 'B,C'
```